# Registering Custom URI Scheme not working on Windows 7 when url has hashtag and question mark

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, registry, uri

So I'm having to register a custom uri, **cnx://**, to have IE launch Chrome.

I've tested my registry entry on Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Everything works fine, except on Win7 when there's a URL with a hashtag and a question mark:

**cnx:// www.url.com/something/#place/page.php?foo=bar**

For whatever reason, that then gets mangled to

**cnx:// www.url.com/something/?foo=bar#place/page.php**

I have tested this by changing the important registry entry from

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CNX\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\Chrome.exe\" %1"
```

to just

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CNX\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k echo %1"
```

which explicitly shows the mangling in a command prompt.

Only happens on Windows 7. 
Works without issues on Win8 and Win10. 
And other URL conventions work just fine on windows7, just not when it has a # and ?

Then, it gets mangled.

And of course, doing http://www.url.com/something/#place/page.php?foo=bar works just fine. It only trips up using this custom uri functionality.

Can anyone maybe offer a workaround?

I tried like crazy encoding #place with %23place but then I lost my mind trying to do the string replacement back to the original #place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: This part merely for demonstration - begin
CALL :sub "cnx:// www.url.com/something/#place/page.php?foo=bar"
CALL :sub "cnx:// www.url.com/something/?foo=bar#place/page.php"
GOTO :eof
:: This part merely for demonstration - end

:sub
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=?#" %%a IN (%1) DO (
 SET "parta=%%a"
 SET "partb=%%b"
 SET "partc=%%c"
)

SET "combo=%parta%#%partb%?%partc%"

IF %* neq "%combo%" SET "combo=%parta%#%partc%?%partb%"

ECHO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe %combo%"

GOTO :EOF
```

ISTM `%1` is supplied differently in Win7, so the trick is to tokenise on `?` and `#`, then reassemble to tokens appropriately.

The key should be

```
@="thisbatch "%1""
```

(I believe - no expert here. Point being that `%1` should be `"quoted"`

---

[response to comments - on-the-fly, untested; probably requires some escapes...]

@="cmd /c cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application&FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=?#" %%a IN ("%1") DO (if "%%a#%%b?%%c"=="%1" (chrome.exe %1) else (chrome.exe %%a#%%c?%%b) )"

Comment: good grief. thank you! but if beggars can be choosers, is there a way to skip the batch file and do it all as a command line? something like cmd /k FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=?#" %%a IN ("%1") DO ( SET "parta=%%a" SET "partb=%%b" SET "partc=%%c" ) SET "combo=%parta%#%partb%?%partc%" IF %* neq "%combo%" SET "combo=%parta%#%partc%?%partb%" set "combo=%combo:cnx:// =%" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" "%combo%"  ? it's not working as is, because I think it needs some ampersands in between commands or to add/remove some percents...just not sure where

Comment: or sorry, CMD /c because in the end it'd be great to close the command window, when it's done. just have it burned into my memory to have it as CMD /K to examine output....

Comment: your response seems to be golden. For anyone else that comes across this, this will only work on Win7 (can probably be edited for 8 and above, but for right now, this works perfectly for my needs). Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yep. It drops a bunch, if not all, of the querystring parameters, unfortunately. I'm sure there's probably some additional edits to be done in the command, but that syntax above, is mostly voodoo to me. God bless you for you proficiency at it. I'm sure you're a treasured asset, for your company.

Comment: Ha! Been unemployed for 16 years now. Employers prefer "new grads" wielding a piece of paper to someone who can tell them why their ill-considered scheme won't work.